# Control flow of fork system call when wait is present or not present

Tags: c, operating-system, fork, wait

In this code (run on linux):

```
void child_process()
{
    int count=0;

    for(;count<1000;count++)
    {
        printf("Child Process: %04d\n",count);
    }
    printf("Child's process id: %d\n",getpid());
}

void parent_process()
{
    int count=0;

    for(;count<1000;count++)
    {
        printf("Parent Process: %04d\n",count);
    }
}


int main()
{
    pid_t pid;
    int   status;        

    if((pid = fork()) < 0)
    {
        printf("unable to create child process\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    if(pid == 0)
        child_process();
    

    if(pid > 0)
    {
        printf("Return value of wait: %d\n",wait();
        parent_process();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If the `wait()` were not present in the code, one of the process (child or parent) would finish it's execution and then the control is given to the linux terminal and then finally the process left (child or parent) would run. The output of such a case is:

```
Parent Process: 0998
Parent Process: 0999
guest@debian:~/c$ Child Process: 0645   //Control given to terminal & then child process is again picked for processing
Child Process: 0646
Child Process: 0647
```

In case `wait()` is present in the code, what should be the flow of execution?

When `fork()` is called then a process tree must be created containing parent and child process. In above code when the processing of child process ends, the parent is informed about the death of child zombie process via `wait()` system call, but parent and child being two separate processes, **is it mandatory that the control is passed the directly to the parent after child process is over?** (no control given to other process like terminal at all) - if yes then it is like child process is a part of parent process (like a function called from another function).

Comment: Capture and print the return values from the system calls (identifying which process is printing by including the return value of `getpid()` in the code.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks, return value of child process' PID and return value of `wait()` is same but it doesn't clear whether the control was **directly** transferred from child to parent and no other process came in-between (like terminal when no `wait()` was used.

Comment: i believe that without wait() the flow is following. - terminal spawns parent process, parent process spawns child process. child process is not taking control, it only has access to the same stdin and stdout. Once the parent process finishes, it exits, and returns control to the terminal, while child runs in the background. With wait: parent process spawns child process, then it executes wait, which waits for the child process to finish. then it executes the rest of the code end exits.

Comment: There's no such guarantee; other processes are allowed to run at any time.  But in a normal use case, there wouldn't be any other processes that are even trying to read or write from this terminal.  The only other likely candidate would be the shell, and it itself is `wait()`ing for the parent to terminate, not doing terminal I/O.

Comment: So in that sense, yes, when a parent `fork()`s a child and then `wait()`s for it, the effect is like a subroutine.

Comment: @effenok in case `wait()` is present - as per your explanation the parent/child processing is same as function call

Comment: @NateEldredge then whats the difference between function calling another function and process creating another process?

Comment: usually the idea is that parent process finishes whatever he is doing, then waits for all child processes to finish what they are doing and then exit. in particular if you first call parent_process(); and then wait() it should make more sense.

Comment: when you spawn the second process, two processes run in parallel to each other. i believe you saw it when you called your code without wait(). Sometimes the processes need to communicate with each other. There are different functions to do it. wait() is one of them. Its functionality is to pause current process and wait for the other process complete. The process calling it is not doing anything, it just waits. So, yes, it makes no sense to call fork() and spawn only one process and then immediately after wait(). This essentially prevents your process to do something in parallel.

Comment: The main application for `fork()` and `wait()` is for the child to call one of the `exec*` functions, to run another program.  You can't do that in a subroutine because `exec*` doesn't return.  This is how `system()` works, and it's what the shell does to run your program in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This comment is, at least, misleading:

```
   //Control given to terminal & then child process is again picked for processing
```

The "terminal" process doesn't really enter into the equation. It's always running, assuming that you are using a terminal emulator to interact with your program. (If you're using the console, then there is no terminal process. But that's unlikely these days.)

The process in control of the user interface is whatever shell you're using. You type some command-line like

```
$ ./a.out
```

and the shell arranges for your program to run. (The shell is an ordinary user program without special privileges, by the way. You could write your own.)

Specifically, the shell:

1. Uses `fork` to create a child process.
2. Uses `waitpid` to wait for that child process to finish.

The child process sets up any necessary redirects and then uses some `exec` system call, typically `execve`, to replace itself with the `./a.out` program, passing `execve` (or whatever) the command line arguments you specified.

That's it.

Your program, in `./a.out`, uses `fork` to create a child and then possibly waits for the child to finish before terminating. As soon as your parent process terminates, the shell's `waitpid()` can return, and as soon as it returns, the shell prints a new command prompt.

So there are at least three relevant processes: the shell, your parent process, and your child process. In the absence of synchronisation functions like `waitpid()`, there are no guarantees about ordering. So when your parent process calls `fork()`, the created child could start executing immediately. Or not. If it does start executing immediately, it does not necessarily preempt your parent process, assuming your computer is reasonably modern and has more than one core. They could both be executing at the same time. But that's not going to last very long because your parent process will either immediately call `exit` or immediately call `wait`.

When a process calls `wait` (or `waitpid`), it is suspended and becomes runnable again when the process it is waiting for terminates. But again there are no guarantees. The mere fact that a process is runnable doesn't mean that it will immediately start running. But generally, in the absence of high load, the operating system will start running it pretty soon. Again, it might be running at the same time as another process, such as your child process (if your parent didn't wait for it to finish).

In short, if you performed your experiment a million times, and your parent waits for your child, then you will see the same result a million times; the child must finish before the parent is unsuspended, and your parent must finish before the shell is unsuspended. (If your parent process printed something *before* waiting, you would see different results; the parent and child outputs could be in any order, or even overlapped.)

If, on the other hand, your parent does not wait for the child, then you could see any of a number of results, and in a million repetitions you're likely to see more than one of them (but not with the same probability). Since there is no synchronisation between parent and child, the outputs could appear in either order (or be interleaved). And since the child is not synchronised with the shell, its output could appear before or after the shell's prompt, or be interleaved with the shell's prompt. No guarantees, other than that the shell will not resume until your parent is done.

Note that the terminal emulator, which is a completely independent process, is runnable the entire time. It owns a pseudo-terminal ("pty") which is how it emulates a terminal. The pseudo-terminal is a kind of pipe; at one end of the pipe is the process which thinks it's communicating with a console, and at the other end is the terminal emulator which interprets whatever is being written to the pty in order to render it in the GUI, and which sends any keystrokes it receives, suitably modified as a character stream back through the pipe. Since the terminal emulator is never suspended and its execution is therefore interleaved with whatever other processes are active on your computer, it will (more or less) immediately show you any output which is sent by your shell or the processes it starts up. (Again, assuming the machine is not overloaded.)